# How to use same reference to refer to more than one class

Tags: java

I need to send the same data to more than one class. My professor gave us a semi-completed driver file, and he uses the same reference to refer to 2 different classes so you can send the same data in one method call, to two classes. However this results in an error. I have been trying to make it work, even by giving them different references and calling the methods twice but it still won't work. It also says that it cannot find symbol "SortedStringListReferenceBased_solution" which is in the signature of the methods. Please help.

```
 public class SortedStringListDriver
{

  public static void main(String [] args)
 {
    SortedStringListArrayBased myGroceryList = new SortedStringListArrayBased();
    SortedStringListReferenceBased myGroceryList = new SortedStringListReferenceBased();

    myGroceryList.add("milk");
    myGroceryList.add("eggs");
    myGroceryList.add("butter");
    myGroceryList.add("pecans");
    myGroceryList.add("apples");
    myGroceryList.add("bread");
    myGroceryList.add("chicken");
    myGroceryList.add("black beans");
    myGroceryList.add("rice");
    myGroceryList.add("sausage");
    myGroceryList.add("flour");

    printList(myGroceryList);//print out original List
    System.out.print("numItems for array based list is now: "+myGroceryList1.size()+"\n\n");


    adding(myGroceryList, "juice");
    removing(myGroceryList, "juice");
    adding(myGroceryList, "banana");
    removing(myGroceryList, "sausage");
    removing(myGroceryList, "cheese");

    }

   public static void adding(SortedStringListReferenceBased_solution myList, String str)
   {
    System.out.println("Adding " + str + " ...");
    myList.add(str);  //add juice
    printList(myList);
    System.out.print("numItems for array based list is now: " + myList.size() + "\n\n");
  }

  public static void removing(SortedStringListReferenceBased_solution myList, String str)
  {
    System.out.println("Removing " + str + " ...");
    myList.remove(str);
    printList(myList);
    System.out.print("numItems is now: " + myList.size() + "\n\n");
  }

  public static void printList(SortedStringListReferenceBased_solution myList)
  {
   //method prints a list, numbering the values,  e.g, "0.  milk" .... "4.  juice".... etc.
    for (int index = 0; index < myList.size(); index++)
    {
      System.out.printf("%2d. %s\n",index, (String) myList.get(index));
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `SortedStringListReferenceBased_solution` is the name of a class that you do not have defined; is that the class you are supposed to create for the assignment? Anyways, the code you have posted would not compile, because you are declaring `myGroceryList` twice. It's not "sending data to two classes at once", it's simply not compiling at all because that isn't valid Java code.

Comment: @ColinD That's very vague and doesn't really address the specific problem at hand.

Comment: I do not believe `SortedStringListReferenceBased_solution` is supposed to be created because the assigment states to implement all the methods in `SortedStringArrayBased` and `SortedStringReferenceBased` and complete the driver: `SortedStringListDriver` and to only submit those files. I am saying an instance is made for both of those classes but the variable used to reference them is the same, (myGroceryList). I do not believe we are supposed to change this unless it is the only way to get it to work.

Comment: @JoeyPlatt It is the only way to get it to work in its current form. I strongly suggest asking your instructor for clarification on this one, because there seems to be a clear gap in what he wants and what you think he wants that we won't really be able to answer for you here.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do: do you want `myGroceryList.add("milk");` to add "milk" to _two_ _separate_ lists?  Or are you trying to add it to one list that could be _either_ `SortedStringListArrayBased` or `SortedStringListReferenceBased`?

Comment: i am trying to add("milk") to two seperate lists

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem, in that the requirements are unclear and can only be clarified by the course instructor.

Comment: If you really want to add to two lists, you'll need to have two different variables for the two lists, and call `.add("milk")` on both of them (and everything else you want to add).  The variable names have to be different.  There's no way to create one variable that will refer simultaneously to the two lists (unless you create a new "multiple-list" class just for that purpose, but I doubt that's what the assignment is asking for).

Comment: For starters, the first 2 statements say "make an an instance of one class called myGroceryList and then u tell the program to clobber that reference with a brand new reference to a different class (the overwriting happens because u used the same variable name myGroceryList. If you were to print out each reference you would see that they are different. One reference cannot be assigned to something twice and retain two separate references...if you reassign the reference then the original one is overwritten

Comment: The requirements are to just get that driver file to run. Here is the pdf for the assignment. https://www.dropbox.com/s/sk08aqohok8t7m0/SortedStringList.pdf

Comment: @ajb This is what I figured and I already did that to my driver file. However I still get a cannot find symbol error for `SortedStringListReferenceBased_solution` in the method signatures. I believe this needs to be replaced with something else but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Ask yourself "how can 2 classes be linked together" "what do I need to do in code to - in a way - make two classes kind of the same thing or have the same behaviours"

Comment: @Justin I truely do not know.

Comment: Anyone? please I need help, my professor did not go over this. He spent all the time explaining how to implement the methods add(), remove(), get(), etc. in the classes `SortedStringArrayBased` and `SortedStringReferenceBased`.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the assignment, I think this is what's needed:

You'll need to set up a variable that can be *either* a `SortedStringListArrayBased` or `SortedStringListReferenceBased`.  But both of those implement `SortedStringListInterface`, so your variable will be declared `SortedStringListInterface`.  You can assign the variable to one or the other.

```
SortedStringListInterface myGroceryList;
if (iWantAnArray)  // I have no idea how to determine this
    myGroceryList = new SortedStringListArrayBased();
else
    myGroceryList = new SortedStringListReferenceBased();
```

Note that when you declare `myGroceryList` as a `SortedStringListInterface`, it means the variable can refer to *any* object that implements that interface, no matter what class it is.  That's probably the answer to the question in your topic line.

Once you have that, you can add your items:

```
myGroceryList.add("milk");
myGroceryList.add("eggs");
...
```

and it will call either the `add` method of `SortedStringListArrayBased` or `SortedStringListReferenceBased` depending on what kind of object you set `myGroceryList` to.  That's polymorphism--it chooses at run time which `add` method actually happens, based on the actual class.

This list of `add` calls (and other calls) should only appear once in your program.  But if you want to do it twice, once for each kind of list, you can put it in a method that's called twice by the main program.  Or you can make the kind of list depend on an argument in `args`, and run the program twice.  I don't know what the professor wants there.  But that part can be changed easily.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I too do not know what would determine if it is one list or the other. This is why I decided to just give them different names (myGroceryList1 and myGroceryList2) and call each method twice. Also I realized that if I changed the method signature to `SortedStringListInterface` it made it run. Thank you again though.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the UML diagram shows that you have an interface and then two classes that implement the interface, indicated by the arrows. An interface lets you say "hey, something that implements this interface will have these methods which I'll leave blank in the interface code" Interfaces are a way to make empty to-be-filled-in-by-implementing-class(es)' methods. So your professor gave you the interface and it's up to you to decide HOW each class should "add" or "remove" something? If a chair implements the movable interface how should it move? Well that depends on the class that implements the interface. If the class that implements it is "WheeledChair" then move() might be "push the darn chair" but "WoodLeggedChair" if it implements the moveable interface might be like "PICK IT UP SO YOU DONT SCRATCH THE FLOOR!" So you need to decide how the methods should be implemented in each. That's the point of an interface mainly - to define an empty set of methods or behaviours when you know that the things that implement the interface will probably need to handle the data in a different way than each other. That way you can ensure the methods get implemented, but leave the details of the implementation open to the implementing classes

Answer (score 0):

Revised code that now works. Not exactly what I wanted to do but it is close enough.

```
public class SortedStringListDriver
{

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    SortedStringListArrayBased myGroceryList1 = new SortedStringListArrayBased();
    SortedStringListReferenceBased myGroceryList2 = new SortedStringListReferenceBased();

    myGroceryList1.add("milk");
    myGroceryList1.add("eggs");
    myGroceryList1.add("butter");
    myGroceryList1.add("pecans");
    myGroceryList1.add("apples");
    myGroceryList1.add("bread");
    myGroceryList1.add("chicken");
    myGroceryList1.add("black beans");
    myGroceryList1.add("rice");
    myGroceryList1.add("sausage");
    myGroceryList1.add("flour");

    myGroceryList2.add("milk");
    myGroceryList2.add("eggs");
    myGroceryList2.add("butter");
    myGroceryList2.add("pecans");
    myGroceryList2.add("apples");
    myGroceryList2.add("bread");
    myGroceryList2.add("chicken");
    myGroceryList2.add("black beans");
    myGroceryList2.add("rice");
    myGroceryList2.add("sausage");
    myGroceryList2.add("flour");

    printList(myGroceryList1);
    printList(myGroceryList2);//print out original List
    System.out.print("numItems for array based list is now: " + myGroceryList1.size() + "\n");
    System.out.print("numItems for referenced based list is now: " + myGroceryList2.size() + "\n\n");

    adding(myGroceryList1, "juice");
    adding(myGroceryList2, "juice");
    removing(myGroceryList1, "juice");
    removing(myGroceryList2, "juice");
    adding(myGroceryList1, "banana");
    adding(myGroceryList2, "banana");
    removing(myGroceryList1, "sausage");
    removing(myGroceryList2, "sausage");
    removing(myGroceryList1, "cheese");
    removing(myGroceryList2, "cheese");
  }

  public static void adding(SortedStringListInterface myList, String str)
  {
    System.out.println("Adding " + str + " ...");
    myList.add(str);  //add juice
    printList(myList);
    System.out.print("numItems for array based list is now: " + myList.size() + "\n\n");
  }

  public static void removing(SortedStringListInterface myList, String str)
  {
    System.out.println("Removing " + str + " ...");
    myList.remove(str);
    printList(myList);
    System.out.print("numItems is now: " + myList.size() + "\n\n");
  }

  public static void printList(SortedStringListInterface myList)
  {
    //method prints a list, numbering the values,  e.g, "0.  milk" .... "4.  juice".... etc.
    for (int index = 0; index < myList.size(); index++)
    {
      System.out.printf("%2d. %s\n\n",index, (String) myList.get(index));
    }
  }

}
```